# SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]TCP Provider

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

Пробую подключить laravel к бд на mssql, и получаю вот такую ошибку:

```
SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (SQL: select top 10 * from [auksion] order by [id] desc)
```

Может кто сталкивался с такой ошибкой?

Answer (score 0):

Sql Server Configuration Manager -> Sql Server Network Configuration -> Protocols For [Ваш SQL инстанс]-> TCP/IP -> IP Adresses -> IpAll

**TCP Dynamic Ports** -убрать значение-
**TCP Port** установить значение 1433